# On an integral over $\log\zeta(s)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, contour-integration, riemann-zeta

I am reading [Harald Cramér's 1919 paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01203390). On page 111, he wrote that by plugging the functional equation for $\zeta(s)$ into ($C=\varepsilon,B=i\varepsilon,A=+i\infty$):
$$
I=z\int_{CBA}e^{zs}\log\zeta(s)\mathrm ds,
$$
there is
$$
I=z\int_{CBA}e^{sz}\left[s\log2\pi-\log\pi+\log\sin\left(\pi s\over2\right)+\log\Gamma(1-s)+\log\zeta(1-s)\right]\mathrm ds.
$$
I am able to follow this argument, but the my concern is on the next step. On the paragraph between (8) and (8a) of his paper, Cramér argues that one needs to correct the above expression into
$$
I=z\int_{CBA}e^{zs}\left[s\log2\pi-\log\pi+\log\sin\left(\pi s\over2\right)+\log\Gamma(1-s)+\log\zeta(1-s)\color{red}{-2\pi i}\right]\mathrm ds.
$$

in order to let the integrand "vary continuously." As I am not familiar with German, I am not able to follow his reasoning. I wonder whether there are simple explanations on why the red term needs to appear.

Comment: Was the omission of $e^{sz}$ in the second integral intentional or a typo? I don't understand what $\int_{CBA}$ means even though I see you defined $C$, $B$, and $A$. Can $\int_{CBA}$ be written as a normal integral with lower and upper evaluation limits, or is it some kind of a path integral?

Comment: @StevenClark That was a typo. I just edited the question, and $\int_{CBA}$ denotes an integral along line segments connecting $C$, $B$, and $A$.

Comment: It looks like they are choosing the branch of the logarithm that will make earlier arguments work out. In particular the point C is mentioned. I am unfamiliar with German so I don't think I can say much more.

Comment: @CrackedBauxite I am using a translator to read this paper, and the author's explanation is that the $2\pi i$ appears because he wants to make $\varepsilon\to0^+$.

Comment: something like: he says the LHS has imaginary part $-\pi i$ at some part, so the same is true of the fifth term on the RHS.  on some other part, the imaginary part of this fifth term is $\pi i$.  (so we need a correcting factor $-2\pi i$)